# UPNP: Bind with multicast

Tags: linux, network-programming, upnp

I have bound my ssdp_socket to 192.168.1.1:1900. To avoid getting upnp msearch requests from the WAN port. But I don't get any SSDP multicast. But if I bind to 0.0.0.0:1900, Every thing works as expected

Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

SSDP uses the multicast address 239.255.255.250. So binding to 192.168.1.1, it's normal you don't see it, whereas binding to 0.0.0.0 (which is INADDR_ANY) it's OK.

If you want to use a specific interface, rather than using its IP you should  bind your socket to this specific interface using setsockopt() and SO_BINDTODEVICE.

Comment: if i bind to the interface. Do i recieve multicast on that interface ?